# Dynamic Timer ListView to expire tickets in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, countdowntimer

I am making an app to keep track of my work tickets and I have a problem with the date. I am using a timer to subtract date1 from date2 but it does not work. The timer count is in days.

What I want to know is: Why do the days change to 0 after a minute?

```
 If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
    Else
        Dim pItem As New ListViewItem
        Timer1.Stop()
        pItem.Text = ComboBox1.Text
        pItem.SubItems.Add(Now.ToString)
        pItem.SubItems.Add(Strings.Format(DateTimePicker1.Value))
        pItem.SubItems.Add(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Now, CDate(DateTimePicker1.Text & " " & Now.TimeOfDay.ToString())).ToString & " Dias")
        '& Now.Hour.ToString & "Horas" & Now.Minute.ToString & "Minutes")
        ListView1.Items.Add(pItem)
        ListView1.Refresh()

        Timer1.Start()
    End If

If Me.ListView1.Items.Count > 0 Then
  For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
    Dim TimeItem As String = Item.SubItems(2).Text  
    Dim DIfference As String = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Now, CDate(TimeItem)).ToString & " Days"
  Next
End If

    Me.ListView1.Refresh()
    'CheckListView()

Public Sub CheckListView()
    For Each item As ListViewItem In Me.ListView1.Items
        If CDate(item.SubItems(2).Text) < Now Then 'Get the date of the item
            Dim NewIt As New ListViewItem
            NewIt.Text = item.Text
            NewIt.SubItems.Add(item.SubItems(1).Text)
            NewIt.SubItems.Add(item.SubItems(2).Text)
            NewIt.SubItems.Add("To Delete")
            Me.ListView1.Items.Add(NewIt)
            ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(item.Index)
        End If
    Next

    ListView1.Refresh()
```

Comment: What you describe is a common ordinary debugging issue.  You have a great debugger at your fingertips, fire it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get what the Timer has to do with it but here is some code you can play with to get what you need.

```
Dim StartDate As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value
Dim CurrentDate As Date = Now
Dim mySpan As TimeSpan = CurrentDate.Subtract(StartDate)
Debug.Print($"Raw Span {mySpan}")
Debug.Print("TotalDays" & CInt(mySpan.TotalDays).ToString)
Debug.Print($"Days: {mySpan.Days}")
Debug.Print($"Hours: {mySpan.Hours}")
```

Comment: ty very much for your time